# Rijndael encryption in python

Tags: python, encryption, aes, rijndael

I wanna use Rijndael encryption with key and block 256bit size in python and padding should be PKCS7. either with utf-8 encode.
I have searched a lot and finally wrote this code, I don't know this is a good way but that's all I know. when run the code I got this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testForRijndael.py", line 1, in <module>
  from rijndael.cipher import crypt
File "/opt/odoo/odoo11-venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/rijndael/cipher/crypt.py", line 1, in <module>
  from rijndael.cipher.blockcipher import *
File "/opt/odoo/odoo11-venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/rijndael/cipher/blockcipher.py", line 64
    raise Exception,"the IV length should be %i bytes"%self.blocksize
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If anybody can help me, I'll be appreciate him/her

This is my code:

```
from rijndael.cipher import crypt
from rijndael.cipher.blockcipher import MODE_CBC
from pkcs7 import PKCS7Encoder


class Rijndael():
    def __init__(self, key, iv):
       self.KEY = key
       self.IV = iv
       self.BLOCKSIZE = 32

   def encrypt(self, plain_text):
        rjn = crypt.new(self.KEY, MODE_CBC , self.IV, 
blocksize=self.BLOCKSIZE)
        pad_text = PKCS7Encoder.encode(plain_text)
        return rjn.encrypt(pad_text).encode()

   def decrypt(self, cipher_text):
       rjn = crypt.new(self.KEY, MODE_CBC , self.IV, 
                       blocksize=self.BLOCKSIZE)
       cipher_text = cipher_text.decode()
       return rjn.decrypt(cipher_text)


  r = Rijndael('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456', 
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzgh3456')
  test_text = "this is a test :)"
  encrypt = r.encrypt(test_text)
  decrypt = r.decrypt(encrypt)
  print(test_text)
  print(encrypt)
  print(decrypt)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `rijndael` library you're importing from is written for python 2, but you're running it with python 3. See below for the syntax that works in python 2, but not python 3.

```
$ cat raise.py
  raise Exception,"text"
$ python2 raise.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raise.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise Exception,"text"
Exception: text
$ python3 raise.py
  File "raise.py", line 1
    raise Exception,"text"
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You can try to migrate it yourself, using the `2to3` tool, see if someone has written a port, or write and execute your program with python 2.

Try `pip2 install rijndael` and then `python2 testForRijndael.py`.

To run `2to3` on the local code (not really recommended but it might work), run `2to3 -w /opt/odoo/odoo11-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rijndael/**/*.py`

Comment: I must run my code with python 3, Is there any rijndael library for python3? I google it but don't find anything, It seems there is no lib for python3 :(